# JSX Compiler Issue for Html Element

Tags: reactjs

Just started out making new UI components in React. Faced the following issue.

I defined the component state.

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {checked:false};
}
```

I use the state in the input tag inside the render function

```
render: function () {
return(
         <div className={this.state.className} onClick={this.clickHandler} >
           <input type="checkbox" ref="innerinput"  {this.state.checked} />;
           <label>Checkbox</label>
        </div>
      )
}
```

It gives the following error:

> { [ReactifyError: /usr/local/src/st/agile/app/App.js: Parse Error:
>   Line 55: Unexpected token this while parsing file:
>   /usr/local/src/st/agile/app/App.js] index: 1149, lineNumber: 55,
>   column: 47, description: 'Unexpected token this', name:
>   'ReactifyError', fileName: '/usr/local/src/st/agile/app/App.js',
>   filename: '/usr/local/src/st/agile/app/App.js', stream:

It seems that the `JSX` supports only "`type=value`" properties and not property like "`checked`" without `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code --> `{this.state.checked}` is only returning false, you need to do this.

`checked={this.state.checked}`